# interacting with kafka over http

Tags: http, request, apache-kafka, message-queue

Elasticsearch seems to have a near full API feature set over http - for example, [indices can be created via a PUT request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html).

Is it currently possible to do the analogous and create a topic, via a http request, in Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box Kafka Admin REST API. In Kafka 0.11 there is a Java AdminClient API so someone can write such an interface as a tool external to the standard Apache Kafka distribution.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-117%3A+Add+a+public+AdminClient+API+for+Kafka+admin+operations

Comment: Rest API development seems active here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest, with admin rest apis planned as mentioned here: http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#features

Comment: @catagory Correct but REST Proxy is part of Confluent Open Source and not part of the base Apache Kafka. It is planned to add REST endpoints for the new KIP-4/AdminClient to REST Proxy in the future

Answer (score 1):

[kafka-manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) has a rich REST API feature-set, including admin features, with a list of all the API routes [here](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/blob/master/conf/routes).